How to store List<> collection data in specific format in C# console application
I am working on a  C# console application and I have an object as shown in image and I want to store this object's data in the specified "Required Format" with "*" and dotted lines  to seperate, appended in the variable(this variable I assign to update a SharePoint online column) along with the data. How I can achieve this? Could anyone please help me in this ASAP.

Required format:
Name: xxxxxxx
Revision:6
System version :43.0
WfItem:23456

Approved By:   xxx
Approved Date :xxxx
Approved Role: xxxxx

Approved By:   xxx
Approved Date :xxxx
Approved Role: xxxxx

